# strange error while debug

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode3.2

I got this error

```
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -L/Users/paxeramed/Desktop/TestWhy/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/paxeramed/Desktop/TestWhy/build/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/paxeramed/Desktop/TestWhy/build/TestWhy.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestWhy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TestWhy.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -o /Users/paxeramed/Desktop/TestWhy/build/Debug-iphoneos/TestWhy.app/TestWhy

ld: framework not found AudioUnit
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I tried the following

clean the project and rebuild
make sure that `@implementation` of main doesn't be repeated
added the audiounit frmaework

I use xcode 3.2.5, any idea how to solve that

I added all the classes in this apple example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html 
to my project except the delegate and the main then in the min view I added the following code to call the  `SpeakHereViewController`

```
SpeakHereViewController* Edit = [[SpeakHereViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpeakHereViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:Edit animated:YES];

[Edit release];
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding `CoreAudio.framework` and `AudioToolbox.framework`,
Try also removing `AudioUnit`.
This fixed it for me.